# write a string based on mysql query

Tags: mysql, subquery

If I have a query that returns first and last name, how would I go about combining them into 1 field?

I want to be able to select an id - then the first and last names are found based on that id, and then they are concatenated for the final returned string.

I am working on a complicated query with many columns being returned - in the past I've gone in with more queries afterwards and replaced some of the values using php.  But I would like to have it all work in the original query.

Right now I'm doing something similar to this:

```
SELECT id From....etc
```

Then afterwards in php I do this query and replace the id with the returned values for first and last name

```
SELECT lastName, firstName FROM people, patient WHERE idpatient = $data AND people_id = id
```

the result is then changed from:

id:1 ---> id: lastname, firstname

is there a way to combine both of these queries into one?

Comment: do the two queries query different databases/tables?

Comment: yes, the id is used as the lookup for the other tables

Comment: in that case, only one table can be queried at a time, so i think its a deadend?

Comment: Are they actually in different databases? or just different tables? Can you post your schema?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, use CONCAT

```
SELECT CONCAT( lastName, firstName ) AS full_name 
FROM people, patient 
WHERE idpatient = $data AND people_id = id
```

Also, you can rewrite this query using explicit JOINs

```
SELECT CONCAT( lastName, firstName ) AS full_name 
FROM people
    INNER JOIN patient ON people_id = id
WHERE idpatient = $data
```

If you're only interested in rows in people that have an entry in patient, or

```
SELECT CONCAT( lastName, firstName ) AS full_name 
FROM people
    LEFT JOIN patient ON people_id = id
WHERE idpatient = $data
```

if you're also interested in rows in people that might not have an entry in patient.